# Webview shows blank screen

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I know the question may be redundant but I've tried many solutions and nothing could have helped me.
In my app, once the user is clicking on a button, it transfers the user to another page. On this page I have a Webview, and a button. They are defined in my xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="1" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="Log out"
    android:id="@+id/btLogot" />

    <WebView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the other hand, I have used `WebViewClient()` and override it with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.
The problem is, nothing happens. 
I think my code is alright, but there's something wrong with my xml and weight of my layouts.

So, what's the matter?!

Comment: remove layout_weight property or change it to "1" or post some part of Controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `layout_weight` is `3` and the while the `layout_weight` of the button is not defined. Moreover you should remove `layout_weight` of the `LinearLayout` ( if you ment `weight sum`, it's not compulsory anyway)

Comment: Yeap, although I figured it out before you say it, but your concern is worth of 1+

Answer (score -1):

Some people from other discussions said: that you should use Relative Layout with the Webview!

You can try doing this =)