# Blank screen in Android webview, happens rarely but happens

Tags: android

From time to time, instead of the webview, we get a blank screen.

A totally blank screen. Stopping the app and reopning it fix the problem.

As this is completely random, we don't really have a way of determining the reason.

Do you know where we should start looking?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043984/webview-shows-blank-screen

Answer (score 0):

1 May be it can be the case of Memory issue, As you say when reopen app all older cache will be remove, Please clear all application or clear the cache memory of your device then restart application , then it should not come,

2 May be it is the case of inter net if it is in use. I am not sure for this.